# How much should one smoke in order to prevent Parkinson's?

Tags: brain, pathology, neurology, neurodegenerative-disorders

There are studies who claim that nicotine has a neuroprotective effect against Parkinson's(such as this: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11772120)

What would be the minimum amount of nicotine(cigarettes smoked) and frequency in order to prevent Parkinson's, at the same time not to damage his health by becoming an addicted smoker?

Comment: The closest thing to an answer you can find is probably in the paper you linked. Did you read it?

Comment: @Remi.b I've read only the abstract, I also tried to obtain the full text(as they described here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/howto/obtain-full-text/) and I didn't manage to find it. Do you know how to obtain it by some other means?

Comment: @Flowryn I am not too sure about this claim. Yes, nicotine may effect dopamine release to some extent but there is no clear consensus on this issue. See the [newer articles that cite](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=5192158566665798626) this paper. In fact [this *J.Neuroscience* paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20410106) says that nicotine free tobacco and decaffeinated coffee can also have neuroprotective effects.

Comment: You will not *prevent* parkinsons by smoking/nicotine consumption, you may see a slight reduction in risk of parkinsons but the effect will be relatively minor and likely outweighed by the negative side effects of smoking/nicotine

Comment: You should probably weigh in the total risk of getting Parkinsons (the German Wikipedia names a prevalence between 1,5 and 2%) compared to the risk of getting lung cancer from smoking which is a lot higher.

Comment: @Flowryn perhaps you can edit your question to remove the emphasis on smoking because eventually people will tell you a lot more about how smoking is bad instead of how nicotine may possibly help Parkinson's patients. You can instead add a note that nicotine can be administered as inhalant, patch or some oral formulation like gums.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the one paper cited is from 2001, and there is a body of research that shows that COPD, a risk factor from smoking, can be a risk factor in the development of Parkinsonism.